# how to fix 'encrypting xml probleme in android studio OR in dont know what is this

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I hope that you have a nice day because I don't.

I opened my android studio project this morning and I get this symboles in my XML code, please help, I need to update the application very soon

I don't know how to solve it

and one other thing I do search on google and I have nothing to help me, also youtube,

I hope that is not a virus.

[image: image 1]

[image]

Comment: You've potentially changed the encoding somewhere? Or your files are corrupt. I notice the alert at the top says some sort of sync failed, could this be the cause? Are you syncing files remotely somewhere? maybe they the sync was interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the file encoding

   **File -> Settings -> Editor -> File encodings -> set UTF-8 for**

   Global Encoding
   Project Encoding
   Default encoding propertie file

   Press OK
2. Rebuild Project

   **Build -> Rebuild project**